# Broken Stick Problem with Zeros + Discrete approach

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I would like to know first if there are studies on the broken stick problem while admitting zeros and secondly if this has some counterpart for discrete length break.

The Broken Stick Problem I am interested in is the following: Given an interval $[0, M]$; after n breaks, what is the probability that each sub-interval has length less than a threshold $\textbf{t}$.

From my knowledge this one is well-known with the following probability that such an event happens:
$$ \phi_n(M, \textbf{t}) = \sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\binom{n}{k}\left(1 - k\cdot\frac{\textbf{t}}{M}\right)^{n-1}_+ $$

More precisely here are my two questions:

- Is there any work that studied the variation with possible sub-intervals of length $0$ ? This seems more complex than just taking the events family $E_i$: "the stick broke in $i$ sub-intervals" for $i \in [| 1, n|]$.
- I am interested in any studies of the two above problems but using discrete break length.

EDIT: Indeed the first question with zeroes in the continuous regim is trivial.

For the discrete part, here is my thinking taking the same approach as the proof for the above $\phi$ (namely by induction)

Without counting the beginning and ending point, there are $n-1$ breaking points. Among these points one is lower than $\textbf{t}$ (as many choices as the number of breaking points: $n-1$).

By fixing $i \in [|0, \textbf{t}|]$, the probability that the aforementioned point is $i$ and is the smallest point is $\left(\frac{M-i}{M}\right)^{n-2}$. Leading to:

\begin{align}
\phi_{n}(M,\textbf{t}) &= (n-1)\cdot \sum_{i=0}^{\textbf{t}}\phi_{n-1}(M,\textbf{t}-i)\cdot\frac{1}{M}\cdot\left(1-\frac{i}{M}\right)^{n-2}\\
&?= \frac{(n-1)!}{M^{n-1}} \cdot\sum_{x_1=0}^{\textbf{t}}\sum_{x_2=0}^{\textbf{t}}\cdots\sum_{x_{n-1}=0}^{\textbf{t}}\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(1 - \frac{x_k}{M - \sum_{j=0}^{k-1}x_j}\right)^{n-k-1}\cdot\phi_1(M-\sum_i^{n-1}x_i, \textbf{t}) \mbox{ with $x_0$ being always 0}
\end{align}

However, first I don't know how to simplify it and secondly it seems harder than necessary.

I am seeing currently a book named "An introduction to Probability theory and its applications Vol.2". They use a change of variable being:
$$ \phi_n(M, \textbf{t}) = \textbf{t}^n(n-1)!u_n(M)\frac{1}{M^{n-1}}$$
which leads to:
$$u_n(M) = \frac{1}{\textbf{t}}\cdot\sum_{i=0}^{t}u_{n-1}(M-i) $$

The goal is to do the induction on this however while there is a hypothesis in their proof ( with continuous argument leading to a integral instead of a sum) it does not apply to this one and would need for a similar induction hypothesis.

Comment: It is not difficult to say the stick is of integer length $k$ and can only be broken at integer points and that more than one break can happen at the same point.  (There are slight complications at the beginning and end, and the ordering of points of equal value, but these are minor)

Comment: It is assumed in your statement that the breaking points are uniformly distributed over the length of the interval. In this case the probability that two points coincide is equal to zero. Therefore the condition of $n$ breaking points is equivalent to $(n+1)$ sub-intervals.  The zero "length" is possible only in discrete case as proposed by @Henry.

Comment: Sorry for the time in between your answer and my edit ... I have done an EDIT highlighting my (short) approach. Is this approach a good start or am I totally wrong somewhere ? @Henry